# TradingView Widget - Font Style Customization

Tags: tradingview-api

We were able to integrate TradingView widget (https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) in our application successfully but we would like to override the font style of the text in the widget so that it aligns well with the our application. Is it possible to do that? If yes, please advise. Thanks
Venkat

We tried overriding the default font style in the widget but it didn't work. We use Poppins font style within our application and would like to apply the same in the widget as well.